# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toDataURL' of null - Cropper JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cropperjs

I am using [jquery cropper](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper) to achieve something like this below. Whenever the user clicks on an input that image will be sent to cropper canvas. And once the user saves the cropped image it will be loaded into the preview box and clear the cropper canvas.

This is what I am trying to achieve
[image]

But the problem with this is, this works great for the first input file. But when I try to do the same with next input it through

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toDataURL' of null

I could not figure out why this is happening when it works great for the first time.

My code is here below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('Input[type="file"]').on('change', function(event) {
    var parent = $(this).closest('div');
    parent.addClass('isSelected');
    cropImage(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]), parent);
  })

})

function cropImage(blob, domElement) {
  var output = document.getElementById('change-profile-pic');
  output.src = blob;
  $('#change-profile-pic').cropper('destroy');
  var $croppedImage = $('#change-profile-pic')
  var result;
  result = $croppedImage.cropper({
    ready: function() {
      console.log('Cropper initialized');
    },
    aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
    crop: function(e) {}
  })


  $('#save').click(function(action) {
    domElement.find('img').attr('src', $croppedImage.cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toDataURL());
    domElement.removeClass('isSelected');

    result.cropper('destroy');
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="image-wraper">
      <input type="file" name="image">
      <div class="image-preview">
        <img src="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-wraper">
      <input type="file" name="image">
      <div class="image-preview">
        <img src="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-wraper">
      <input type="file" name="image">
      <div class="image-preview">
        <img src="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="crop-image-section">
      <img src="" id="change-profile-pic">
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

I added code to the  [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/us2sm3xm/xpvt214o/667198/)

Can anyone please tell me where I m doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/issues/624

Comment: @Phil,hi thank you but that is not the case this time. One weird thing about this code is that even though it is giving that error, if I console log the `$croppedImage.cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toDataURL()` I still get base64 encoded image string only thing is that copper does not destroy, rather it initialize itself without taking any options i have provided.

Answer (score 1):

there, please put your scripts to the bottom of the document in order to render the canvas first.

So this does mean you should move the scripts.

```html
<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="image-wraper">
      <input type="file" name="image">
      <div class="image-preview">
        <img src="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-wraper">
      <input type="file" name="image">
      <div class="image-preview">
        <img src="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-wraper">
      <input type="file" name="image">
      <div class="image-preview">
        <img src="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="crop-image-section">
      <img src="" id="change-profile-pic">
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here's my modified version.